seven-segment display incomplete
I need to create a seven segment display, printing the results side by side, the results I get are printed with a \n after each number.
# ### ### 
#   #   # 
# ### ### 
# #     # 
# ### ### 

I've tried print("x",sep=" ") without success, this is my code:
nums = {
    '0': "###\n" + "# #\n" * 3 + "###",
    '1': "#\n" * 5,
    '2': "###\n" + "  #\n" + "###\n" + "#  \n" + "###",
    '3': "###\n" + "  #\n" + "###\n" + "  #\n" + "###",
    '4': "# #\n" * 2 + "###\n" + "  #\n" * 2,
    '5': "###\n" + "#  \n" + "###\n" + "  #\n" + "###",
    '6': "###\n" + "#  \n" + "###\n" + "# #\n" + "###",
    '7': "###\n" + "  #\n" * 4,
    '8': "###\n" + "# #\n" + "###\n" + "# #\n" + "###",
    '9': "###\n" + "# #\n" + "###\n" + "  #\n" + "  #"
}


def res(num_list):
    num_list = list(str(num_list))
    try:
        for i in num_list:
            print(nums[i], sep=" ")
    except:
        print("Invalid numbers")


res(12)

Result:
#
#
#
#
#

###
  #
###
#  
###

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

You can't print each multiline digit in full; you need to print the first row of each digit, then the second row of each digit, etc.

I've tried print("x",sep=" ") without success Of course, because the number displays already contain embedded newlines...

Like @chepner pointed out in the comment, you would have to print all digits together, one row at a time, which can be done by zipping together lines of the digits into rows:
def res(num_list):
    for row in zip(*(nums[n].splitlines() for n in str(num_list))):
        print(*row)

so that:
res(1234567890)

outputs:
# ### ### # # ### ### ### ### ### ###
#   #   # # # #   #     # # # # # # #
# ### ### ### ### ###   # ### ### # #
# #     #   #   # # #   # # #   # # #
# ### ###   # ### ###   # ###   # ###

Demo: https://ideone.com/veWhmS
